# Why my order by is not sorting correctly using to_char function in a date column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get the last statistics of my db schema. I am using this query:

```
COL last_analyzed FOR A30;
col stale_stats for a11;
col table_name for a40;
col owner for a30;
SET LINESIZE 2000;
select owner,NVL(TO_CHAR(last_analyzed, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'NO STATS') last_analyzed,count(*) last_analyzed_count
from dba_tab_statistics
where owner = 'EXAMPLE'
group by owner,TO_CHAR(last_analyzed, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
order by 2 asc
/
```

But my sort is:

```
OWNER                          LAST_ANALYZED                  LAST_ANALYZED_COUNT
------------------------------ ------------------------------ -------------------
EXAMPLE                         07/05/2021                                    1
EXAMPLE                         11/06/2021                                    32
EXAMPLE                         26/04/2021                                    169
EXAMPLE                         27/04/2021                                    1
EXAMPLE                         NO STATS                                      1
```

Here, we can see the month 06 is after month 05.

Comment: Because you're formatting dates as strings, and then putting the smallest part (day) first.  Try `yyyy/mm/dd`, because then each digit is in size order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dates are being sorted *as strings*, so the sorting is 100% correct.

My recommendation is that you use ISO standard formatting:

```
select owner,
       coalesce(TO_CHAR(last_analyzed, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'NO STATS') last_analyzed,count(*) last_analyzed_count
from dba_tab_statistics
where owner = 'EXAMPLE'
group by owner, TO_CHAR(last_analyzed, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
order by 2 asc;
```

But if you really want to persist with the bespoke date format, you can instead use an `ORDER BY`:

```
order by owner, min(dba_tab_statistics.last_analyzed)
```

Comment: Nope, Gordon; you can't use aggregate function in GROUP BY. You'll get "ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here" error.

Comment: No problem at all :)

Comment: Both options worked well, thanks. I prefer to preserve the o dd/mm/yyyy because it's the default date format in my country. One note is: I have needed to change the alias "last_analyzed" to "last_analyzed_date". Using the same column name in the alias doesn't work, I got the same result as my example.

Comment: @Harry . . . Or qualify the reference in the `ORDER BY` so it is unambiguous.

Comment: Thanks, qualify is better. has Worked fine here.